# Node Js sequelize raw queries change to ORM for latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, select, sequelize.js

I am trying to covert my sequelize raw queries to `ORM`, but am not get proper result.

**This is my raw queries**

```
var query = "SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('40.892389') ) * cos( radians( c.shopLatitude ) ) * cos( radians( c.shopLongitude ) - radians('-74.258633') ) + sin( radians('40.892389') ) * sin(radians(shopLatitude)) ) ) AS distance FROM cubbers c HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance ASC";

db.sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT} ).then(dataList=>{
    res.send(dataList)
}).catch(error=>{
    res.send('error')
});
```

**ORM:**

```
CubbersShopsData.findOne({
    where: { cubbersId: data.cubbersId },
    include: [ CubbersAvailability ],
    attributes: [[sequelize.literal("3959 * acos(cos(radians("+shopLatitude+")) * cos(radians(shopLatitude)) * cos(radians("+shopLongitude+") - radians(shopLongitude)) + sin(radians("+shopLatitude+")) * sin(radians(shopLatitude)))"),'distance']],
    logging: console.log
}).then(dataList=>{
    res.send(dataList)
}).catch(error=>{
    res.send('error')
});
```

In my ORM code i want to add `orderBy` and `having`.

If am adding `order:['distance', 'ASC'],` it show this error

> `Unknown column 'cubbers.distance' in 'order clause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, sequelize has some [problems](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7975) with using aliases in having and order clauses. Therefore, I always use `sequelize.literal` method in such cases.

```js
CubbersShopsData.findOne({
    where: { cubbersId: data.cubbersId },
    include: [ CubbersAvailability ],
    attributes: [[sequelize.literal("3959 * acos(cos(radians("+shopLatitude+")) * cos(radians(shopLatitude)) * cos(radians("+shopLongitude+") - radians(shopLongitude)) + sin(radians("+shopLatitude+")) * sin(radians(shopLatitude)))"),'distance']],
    having: sequelize.literal('distance < 20'),
    order: sequelize.literal('distance ASC'),
    logging: console.log
}).then(dataList=>{
    res.send(dataList)
}).catch(error=>{
    res.send('error')
});
```

Comment: Can please refer me some tutorials for sequelize query builder

Comment: @RameshS I wish I could, but I don't know any. All I have is just practical experience.